# Alternative or Improvement to Eclipse JDT SearchEngine

Tags: java, eclipse, search, eclipse-jdt

I'm looking for a way to either improve the run-time of Eclipse's SearchEngine class, or another search technique that could replace it. Currently I'm searching for all references of ALL methods within a given project's source files. This technique runs fine for smaller projects, but the run-time grows exponentially and becomes useless on projects over a few MBs.

The current code I'm using to find the method references is:

```
public void processProject(IJavaProject javaProject) throws JavaModelException{
    initializeEngine(javaProject);
    for(IPackageFragment pkg : javaProject.getPackageFragments()){
        if(pkg.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE){
            for(ICompilationUnit unit : pkg.getCompilationUnits()){
                System.out.println("Unit: " + unit.getElementName());
                for(IType type : unit.getTypes()){
                    for(IMethod method : type.getMethods()){
                        //getReferenceMatches(method, javaProject);
                        searchFor(method);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
public void initializeEngine(IJavaProject searchIn) throws JavaModelException{
    ArrayList<IPackageFragmentRoot> roots = new ArrayList<IPackageFragmentRoot>();
    for(IPackageFragmentRoot root : searchIn.getPackageFragmentRoots()){
        if(root.getKind() == IPackageFragmentRoot.K_SOURCE)
            roots.add(root);
    }
    IJavaElement[] elems = new IJavaElement[roots.size()];
    elems =  roots.toArray(elems);

    scope = SearchEngine.createJavaSearchScope(elems);


    engine = new SearchEngine();
    participants = new SearchParticipant[]{SearchEngine.getDefaultSearchParticipant()};


}
//search for methods, or other element type
public void searchFor(IJavaElement elem){
    requestor = new SimpleRequestor();
    pattern = SearchPattern.createPattern(elem, IJavaSearchConstants.REFERENCES);
    try{
        engine.search(pattern, participants, scope, requestor, null);
    }catch(CoreException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
class SimpleRequestor extends SearchRequestor{
private ArrayList<SearchMatch> matches;

public SimpleRequestor(){
    super();
    matches = new ArrayList<SearchMatch>();
}
@Override
public void acceptSearchMatch(SearchMatch match) throws CoreException {
    if(match.getAccuracy() == SearchMatch.A_ACCURATE);
        matches.add(match);
}

public ArrayList<SearchMatch> getMatches(){
    return matches;
}

}
```

scope, engine, pattern, participants, and requestor are all global vars.

I'm not currently saving the results, because right now all I'm worried about is the run-time of the search. Would a straight scan (run through each source file and save all reference instances) be quicker? Is there a way to boost the SearchEngine?

It seems as though if I use the built-in Eclipse search (right-click on method->references->project) works very quickly as opposed to this programmatic version, but I may be wrong. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Don't think the SearchEngine was designed to do a search of all references of all methods. I would suspect that your code effectively goes over the same source files several times.

The built in search works faster probably because you are searching for references of only one method there.

There are some details captured here about SearchEngine internals - http://wiki.eclipse.org/JDT_Core_Programmer_Guide#Search_Engine - which may give you some insight as to what is happening.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I understand that this search routine that I'm using will traverse through the same sources several times, and that's why I'm searching for an alternative. Even though the built in search is only using one method at a time, it still seems much faster (by an order of magnitude), than the results I'm getting. What I'm searching for is an alternative to this, and as you pointed out, the SearchEngine was most likely not made for this purpose. Any other code search suggestions?

Comment: I ended up using ASTVisitor, it works much better for your reasoning.